# Python nested loop patterns - star with gaps in-between

Tags: python, loops, nested

I'm new and I'm unable to replicate the following:

```
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```

I'm using loops to create all kinds of triangles but I just can't figure out how to count for the spaces in the code.

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * *
```

Is there a page/video that directly explains the loop?

Comment: I don’t see any loops here. Maybe you should paste in some code. Or maybe search the archives. This problem has been discussed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a page or video for you, but worked out a solution myself. So what we are trying to do here is to print 4 lines with an increasing number of stars for each line on both sides of some spaces. So all we have to is setup a loop that counts the number of stars and counts how many spaces we need to place between them. Each line has 8 characters so we would have this many space per line: 8 - 2 * number of starts. Here is some code that implements my solution:

```py
for i in range(1,5):
  spaces = 8 - 2*i
  for j in range(i):
    print('*', end='')
  for j in range(spaces):
    print(' ', end='')
  for j in range(i):
    print('*', end='')
  print()
```